# How to open a link in default browser using JavaMe?

Tags: mobile, java-me

Need to be cross-device -working for every mobile manufacturer that gives support to **JavaME**-

In particular: when the application is open, it redirects to a (cabled) link in the default browser of the mobile device.

Found how to do it in a **not** mobile Java app, but have not found example for **JavaME**.

I'm using JavaME, with Sun Java Wireless Tool Kit 2.5.2, and eclipseME.

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to do:

```
        try {
        platformRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        destroyApp(true);
        notifyDestroyed();
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But not sure about if it will work in all platforms. Also, why the app must be destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is how, please read the comments of the code:

```
            // In startApp()

    boolean mustExit = false;
    try {

        /**
         * mustExit - Boolean
         * 
         * Some MIDP platforms are more restricted than others.
         * For example, some don't support concurrent processing,
         * so the MIDlet must exit before the platform can honor
         * a service request.
         * 
         * If <true> destroy the app. So the browser
         * can start.
         */
        mustExit = platformRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(mustExit){
        destroyApp(true);
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
```

Also, if you are under Linux, you must set a default browser for the emulator. Go to `yourPath/Java/lib/system.config` and, at the end, add the following line:

```
# Associate the Mozilla browser with platformRequest() - Linux
com.sun.midp.midlet.platformRequestCommand: /usr/bin/firefox
```

(could be another browser of course)

Now run it in your emulator.Or create the **.jad** and **.jar** an run it in your physical phone.